# Why is my first-child selector not working on the first element in a selection with a specified class?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I'm a little clueless as to the correct use of `first-child`.

I have a (dynamically generated) element, which eventually will include:

```
<h1>
  <a>Foo</a>
  <a.trigger>Trigger A</a>
  <a.trigger>Trigger B</a>
  <span.bar>Bar</span>
</h1>
```

I need to style both the `trigger` links. This is what I'm doing:

```
.ui-collapsible-tabs.ui-dynamic-tabs .ui-collapsible-heading a.trigger {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2em;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 2em;
}
.ui-collapsible-tabs.ui-dynamic-tabs .ui-collapsible-heading a.trigger:first-child {
  right: 0;
  background-color: red !important;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

I have tried both `a.trigger:first-child` and `a.trigger:nth-of-type(1)` but I'm not able to override the CSS set by the first rule. Both selectors have same specificity, too, so that cannot be the reason.

**Question:**
I guess I'm missing something obvious... maybe someone can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: A class is not specified in HTML the same way as in CSS, so you would want `<a class="trigger">` to have an anchor tag with the class `trigger`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:first-child` matches the first child of its parent. Your first `a.trigger` is not the first child — that would be the classless `a` before it.

`:first-of-type` and `:nth-of-type(1)`, which are equivalent, match the first element of its type within its parent. In this case, your classless `a` is also the first `a` of its parent, making your first `a.trigger` the second `a` element.

Is your given structure how your dynamic element will always be generated? If so, you can simply select `a.trigger:nth-child(2)` instead of `a.trigger:first-child`:

```
.ui-collapsible-tabs.ui-dynamic-tabs .ui-collapsible-heading a.trigger:nth-child(2) {
  right: 0;
  background-color: red !important;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

Or you can try `a + a.trigger`:

```
.ui-collapsible-tabs.ui-dynamic-tabs .ui-collapsible-heading a + a.trigger {
  right: 0;
  background-color: red !important;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

(That `!important` probably isn't needed by the way.)

Otherwise if you need to select the first `a.trigger` in general you will need to order your declarations differently and change up your selectors a bit:

```
.ui-collapsible-tabs.ui-dynamic-tabs .ui-collapsible-heading a.trigger {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  background-color: red !important;
  border: 0 none;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 2em;
}
.ui-collapsible-tabs.ui-dynamic-tabs .ui-collapsible-heading a.trigger + a.trigger {
  right: 2em;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-right: 0 none;
}
```

If your two `a.trigger`s aren't always adjacent, replace `+` with `~`.

The generic solution is covered in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107).

Comment: ah, so first-child only matches elements, not any classes I set on them?

Comment: @frequent: Yes. Is your given structure how your dynamic element will always be generated? If so, you can simply select `a.trigger:nth-child(2)` instead of `a.trigger:first-child`.

Comment: I can tell you like these CSS selector questions. You really jump on them fast boltclock. 1+

Comment: @BoltClock: there is either 1 trigger, 2 triggers or none. let see if it works.

Comment: @Josh C: I call it my specialty tag :) If you look at my profile you'll see [css-selectors] featured very prominently.